# jQuery .click() works in Firebug, but not a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am attempting to write my first userscript using Greasemonkey, in Firefox. I have done a good bit of research because I am new to userscripts and jQuery but I can't seem to get this simple test script to work. So far I have this in the `Test.user.js` file:

```
// ==UserScript 
// @name            Desk Notifications 
// @description     Displays special notifications to NVOWS coaches at desk.com
// @downloadURL     http://www.example.com/deskNotifications.user.js
// @include         http://nvows.desk.com/agent
// @namespace       http://www.example.com/userscripts
// @updateURL       http://www.example.com/deskNotifications.meta.js
// @version         0.1
// @grant           none
// ==/UserScript 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert('Script loaded.'); 
    $('.interaction_type_60').click(function() { 
        alert("You clicked a case!"); 
    }); 
    $('.interaction_type_40').click(function() { 
        alert("You clicked a case!"); 
    }); 
});
```

What I need it to do is obviously a lot more complicated but because I am new to jQuery and userscripts I just wanted to make this work first. So far the "Script Loaded." is being displayed so that rules out a lot of possible problems. When I run only this part of the code in firebug it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert('Script loaded.'); 
    $('.interaction_type_60').click(function() { 
        alert("You clicked a case!"); 
    }); 
    $('.interaction_type_40').click(function() { 
        alert("You clicked a case!"); 
    }); 
});
```

So that rules out having code errors or grabbing a wrong class selector. I can't see what could be the issue if the code is right and it is being executed. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated. I am not a newbie to programming. Just web based stuff.
Here is the part of the HTML page that I am trying to see when it is clicked.

```
<tbody id="ticket_filter_list_items" class=" ">
<tr id="ticket_filter_item_73354627" class="ticket_filter_item ticket_filter_item_table_view interaction_type_60 ticket_filter_item_open ticket_filter_item_current_selected" onclick=" ticketEditTableView(73354627, event);return false; " data-in-search="" data-ticket-id="73354627" style="">
<tr id="ticket_filter_item_73382205" class="ticket_filter_item ticket_filter_item_table_view interaction_type_40 ticket_filter_item_open " onclick=" ticketEditTableView(73382205, event);return false; " data-in-search="" data-ticket-id="73382205" style="">
</tbody>
```

*This is off topic and not a big deal but if you see something that would make this userscript execute  on pages that aren't 'http://nvows.desk.com/agent' then let me know. It says "Script loaded." every time I go to Stack Overflow. Ha.*
**--------------------------------------


UPDATE:** I just tried to do this for testing:

```
$(document)
.on('click', this, function(){
    alert('Please Work!!!!');
})
```

The things that I have been trying to click this whole time are the things that are not displaying the message. All of them are loaded with javascript after the page is loaded. I am almost positive that is the reason they will not allow me to click them. Is there a way to click these items. In the HTML script they look the same as the other elements.

Comment: Can you add your markup to the question?

Comment: @iMoses I am unsure what you mean? Once again, I am new to web stuff. I am not sure what markup you are talking about.

Comment: He is asking to see the HTML portion of your code

Comment: @mplungjan I can try it out. But why would the way I have it run in firebug and not in an actual script?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Oh. I should have thought about that. I don't have any HTML. I am making a userscript that uses the website desk.com. I guess you can't see that though without an account. It is a ton of code so I will edit the original post to include the part I am trying to affect.

Comment: I ment the html which is relevant to your code

Comment: If the script is running on every page, then it has (or had) a corrupt metadata block.  There also may be more than one version of the script operating.  The block currently in your question looks fine, but if it has any leading spaces it will not be parsed correctly! ... ... 

Open the Script manager (***Tools -> Greasemonkey -> Manage User Scripts***) and delete any scripts that fire on that page.  Then restart Firefox and reinstall your script.

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks. I will give it a go. It was starting to get really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you've ran the code on the firebug console and it works fine, which leave very little options here.
I believe that the HTML tags you are trying to add those events to haven't been created yet. This will happen if those elements are created via JavaScript and the code which creates them hasn't run yet. Another possibility is that the elements are on the DOM but haven't received those classes yet, also might happen if the classes are given using JavaScript.

Give this code sample a try, see if it helps (let me know the results):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert('Script loaded.'); 
    $(document)
        .on('click', '.interaction_type_60', function() { 
            alert("You clicked a case!"); 
        })
        .on('click', '.interaction_type_40', function() { 
            alert("You clicked a case!"); 
        }); 
});
```

**Notice**: The elements you are trying to attach those events to **MUST** be present on the DOM when your original code run and they must have the classes you defined. What my code does is attached the event to the document element and looks for a click event bubbling up the chain of elements, allowing you to add new elements containing those selector and the listeners will be called without you needing to attach the event handler specifically to those elements.

P.S.

In this specific case you don't even need the `$(document).ready(..)` part. You can just use:

```
$(document)
    .on('click', '.interaction_type_60', function() { 
        alert("You clicked a case!"); 
    })
    .on('click', '.interaction_type_40', function() { 
        alert("You clicked a case!"); 
    });
```

Because the events are attached to the document element which is always present.

**Edit:** After seeing you markup I believe the problem may also be that the inline `onclick` events use `return false;` which might be preventing the events from bubbling further up the chain.

Comment: First off let me say "Thank you!" for the great response. I think I got what you are saying. You are absolutely correct. The classes don't exist in the html when the page is loaded. I watch them populate with Firebug when I refresh the page. So I see why mine wasn't working. But once they are on the page I can run the script, which is why running it in Firebug worked. But what you are saying is by using .on() function it will listen to the click to see if it was on '.interactoin_type_60'. That makes since to me but when I run this in firebug or in the actual script it gives no results.

Comment: I am going to read about the .on() function now to see what I can figure out. You have been such a help to me. 

Also, I edited the original post to show some HTML from the site I am running the script on.

Comment: First of all you welcome. I've seen the HTML and if you'll read my last edit you'll see I replied about it. Unfortunately I was wrong and apparently the `return false` shouldn't interfere as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/m8mAZ/

Comment: But the `ticketEditTableView()` function may be blocking `.on()`.

Comment: I thought about it and it seems unlikely but possible. It might be preventing further bubbling.

Comment: @DustinGriffith, did this really fix your problem?  You said `"when I run this in firebug or in the actual script it gives no results."`.  If it did work, please clarify.  If it didn't, I can provide an answer that will work.

Comment: The real answer is no. It didn't work. His answer informed me of how things work and with the information I provided it would work as showed in the example iMoses gave above. I believe the problem is the item actually being clicked isn't the one it looks like I am clicking. I can get it to display the desired results when the user clicks on other elements, such as empty space in a <ul>. But when I change the selector to the element they are clicking it doesn't work anymore. I wish there was a way to say if they click anything inside the <ul id="myUnsortedList"> to perform an this action.

Comment: @BrockAdams So I guess I am done with the original problem but I can't get the new problem fixed. I may have to post about that after some more research. I have this example: (http://jsfiddle.net/2SM6Q/1/). You can see that I am trying to click any item in the <ul> It is exactly what I want it to be. When I put it in a userscript it doesn't work. It loades the script but when I click within the <ul> it doesn't display my message. Driving me a little crazy.

Comment: @DustinGriffith, It works on the fiddle but not the script?  Does the real HTML have `onclick` attributes? It could be AJAX delays coupled with event propagation blocks, again.  And/or it could be how the script is using jQuery and the sandbox. Also check the Firefox Error Console (***Ctrl+Shift+J***), not just the Firebug console, for errors. ... Any more than that calls for a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You say, when you run the original `.click()` code from Firebug it works.

As iMoses pointed out, it doesn't work from a Greasemonkey script because the script fires before the page's javascript creates the targeted nodes.

You also report that the `.on()` code does not work from either the script or Firebug.  That means that the `onclick` function of your target nodes ( `ticketEditTableView()` ) is stopping event bubbling. It probably calls `event.stopPropagation()`.

The solution is to go back to `.click()` but apply it as the target nodes are added to the page.  This can be done with [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891).

Here is **a complete script** that uses `waitForKeyElements` to bind `.click()` to those nodes as they are added to the page:

```
// ==UserScript
// @name        Desk Notifications
// @description Displays special notifications to NVOWS coaches at desk.com
// @downloadURL http://www.example.com/deskNotifications.user.js
// @include     http://nvows.desk.com/agent
// @namespace   http://www.example.com/userscripts
// @updateURL   http://www.example.com/deskNotifications.meta.js
// @version     0.1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant GM_addStyle directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements (
    ".interaction_type_60, .interaction_type_40", addAlertOnClick
);

function addAlertOnClick (jNode) {
    jNode.click (alertOnClick);
}

function alertOnClick (zEvent) {
    var targNode    = $(zEvent.currentTarget);
    var messageStr  = "Oopsie!";

    if (targNode.hasClass ("interaction_type_60") ) {
        messageStr  = "You clicked a type 60 case!"
    }
    else if (targNode.hasClass ("interaction_type_40") ) {
        messageStr  = "You clicked a type 40 case!"
    }

    alert (messageStr);
}
```

Comment: OK. I tried out the code but I don't see what would cause messageStr to display. I looked up waitForKeyElements but I could only find it on github so I followed the code to see what it does. I wanted to see if the function was even working so I made a test script to see if I could make a message display when the element with the class .ui-tabs-selected was loaded. This element is created after the initial load of the page. Here is my script:
waitForKeyElements (
    ".ui-tabs-selected", addAlert
);

function addAlert (jNode) {
 alert('ui-tabs-selected was loaded');
}
This never displays.

Comment: **Correction.** The above code worked. I don't know why it wasn't working at first but it is now working. I have used this to solve this problem. I do have a new problem that is a lot simpler. [View Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402984/display-a-message-using-waitforkeyelements-every-time-a-class-is-added-to-elem) I will post my own answer if I get it working.