# Display a message, using waitForKeyElements, every time a class is added to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have been learning javascript, jQuery, and userscripts, as well as how to user firebug, the last 3 days in the attempt to display information about a selected customer on the website desk.com. So far, other than a lot of learning, I have little to show for. I simply can't get the message to update when a new tab is selected.

[image]

The purple tab is the selected one. All I need to do is when a new tab is selected display a message. For testing lets just put this message in an javascript alert(). Here is the HTML for the entire top bar that contains the Customer 1 tab.

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner all">
  <li class="a-icons ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a id="tab-tickets-label" href="#tabs-tickets">
      <img width="18" height="16" src="https://d3jyn100am7dxp.cloudfront.net/images/a-icon-agent-list.png?1352530323" alt="">
     </a>
  </li>
  <li class="a-icons ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a id="tab-kb" href="#tabs-kb">
      <span>
        <img width="16" height="17" src="https://d3jyn100am7dxp.cloudfront.net/images/a-icon-knowledge-base.png?1352530323" alt="">
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="a-icons a-last ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a id="tab-search" href="#tabs-search">
      <span>
        <img width="18" height="17" src="https://d3jyn100am7dxp.cloudfront.net/images/a-icon-search.png?1352530323" alt="">
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a id="tab_header_ticket_id_73354627" href="#tabs-tid_88be8cc0-116b-0130-bf8a-12313f070061">
      <span id="tabs-tid_88be8cc0-116b-0130-bf8a-12313f070061-closer" class="tab_closer">
      </span>
      <span>
      <span id="tabs-tid_88be8cc0-116b-0130-bf8a-12313f070061-icon" class="top_tab_icon">
        <img width="20" height="20" src="https://d3jyn100am7dxp.cloudfront.net/images/interactions/20/a-phone.png?1352530323" alt="">
      </span>
      <span id="tabs-tid_88be8cc0-116b-0130-bf8a-12313f070061-customer-name" class="top_tab_customer_name">Customer 2</span>
      </span>
      <span id="tabs-tid_88be8cc0-116b-0130-bf8a-12313f070061-service-level-bar" class="tab_service_level_indicator"> </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
    <a id="tab_header_ticket_id_73382205" href="#tabs-tid_88cd2df0-116b-0130-1271-12313f06c46f">
      <span id="tabs-tid_88cd2df0-116b-0130-1271-12313f06c46f-closer" class="tab_closer"></span>
      <span>
        <span id="tabs-tid_88cd2df0-116b-0130-1271-12313f06c46f-icon" class="top_tab_icon">
          <img width="20" height="20" src="https://d3jyn100am7dxp.cloudfront.net/images/interactions/20/a-email.png?1352530323" alt="">
        </span>
        <span id="tabs-tid_88cd2df0-116b-0130-1271-12313f06c46f-customer-name" class="top_tab_customer_name">Customer 1</span>
      </span>
      <span id="tabs-tid_88cd2df0-116b-0130-1271-12313f06c46f-service-level-bar" class="tab_service_level_indicator"> </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the above code the element with the class 'ui-tabs-selected' is a `<li>`. This class is added to the newly selected tab every time a new tab is selected. I need my script to display a message, say "a new customer is selected", every time the class 'ui-tabs-selected' is added to a new element.

Here is the scriptAttemp.user.js that I have tried most recently.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          deskNotifications2
// @namespace     http://www.dutgriff.com/userscripts
// @description   Notifications for desk.com
// @include       https://nvows.desk.com/agent*
// @version       1.0
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require       https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements (
    ".ui-tabs-selected", addAlert
);

function addAlert (jNode) {
    alert('The user was selected.');
}
```

**The above script works great at first.** It will display the message when the page loads. It will display the message again if I select a new tab. Then when I select a new tab again it does nothing.

I need it to display the message every time a new tab is selected, or every time the '.ui-tabs-selected' is moved to a new location. This class can move to a new location by clicking other things on the page, not just by clicking on a different tab.

For instance when there are no customer-tab selected I can click a button to view a new customer. This will open a new tab and place the '.ui-tabs-selected' on this new tab. All advice/links to info pages/constructive criticism is greatly appreciated. Sorry I am so new to all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`waitForKeyElements()`](https://gist.github.com/2625891) only fires once per individual node found. But, what you want is to fire when that class (`ui-tabs-selected`) ***moves*** from one node to another.

This means that you must track the old node, and see if it is the same as the new node.  And if you use `waitForKeyElements()`, you must tell it to run more than once on individual found nodes.  You can do that by having the callback function (`addAlert()` in this case) return `true`.

Putting it all together, your script would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          deskNotifications2
// @namespace     http://www.dutgriff.com/userscripts
// @description   Notifications for desk.com
// @include       https://nvows.desk.com/agent*
// @version       1.0
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require       https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements (
    ".ui-tabs-selected", addAlert
);

function addAlert (jNode) {
    if (typeof this.lastNode == "undefined"  ||  this.lastNode != jNode[0]) {
        alert('The user was selected.');
    }
    this.lastNode = jNode[0];

    return true;    // Allow repeat firings for this node.
}
```